# Latin abbreviation to use in English to replace "as such"

Tags: british-english, abbreviations, latin

I was wondering if I can use "et al." in order to say "as such" after a list of elements in a sentence given as example.

If not:

- What can be the correct Latin abbreviation to use to replace "as such"?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure why you you would commonly need to say "as such" after a list.  Can you give an example?

Comment: Yes, I'm not clear on how one would say "as such" after a list of elements in English, never mind in Latin.

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_%28T%29) lists  *talis qualis* as Latin for “just as such” and annotates it as “such as it is” or “as such”

Comment: Don't you guys say ".. ingredients like potatoes, carrots and such."? Because we sure do.

Comment: Yes, we might.  But "as such" is not "such".  "As such" is a specific formulation of phrase that has a specific meaning.  See Wiktionary: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_such

Comment: @Phil there is a huge difference between *and such* and *as such*. The abbreviation you're looking for is *etc.* (*et cetera*) meaning *and others*

Comment: If you are indeed looking for an abbreviation for ***and such***, the most obvious answer is ‘etc.’ as @JohnQPublic says. Hard to tell when in your question you’ve only written “as such”, which means something entirely different and makes no sense at the end of a list.

Comment: Sorry that should say *and so forth* and **not** *and others* above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"As such" and "et al." are not synonyms.  "As such" is not used after a list of things, but "et al." is.  It is used to say "and so on" or "and others".

"This film is ideal for action stars such as Arnold Schwarzenegger and Sylvester Stallone, et al."

If you want Latin for "as such", it is "per se", but it is not abbreviated.

"This was not negligence, per se, but absent-mindedness."

Comment: Arnold and Sylvester are both humans so "as such" wouldn't work. But if one were to say "cats, dogs and such." I believe it would. It would then be referring to *such* kinds.

Comment: @Phil, "as such" is not the same as "such" in your sentence.  And you will note that I did not use "as such" in the Arnold and Sylvester example -- not least because "as such" does not fit in the sentence's meaning.

Comment: Thank you very much, I notice the fault I made and understand your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use *et al.* for that. *Et al.* basically means *and others* or refers to a group.

There's not one that I can think of that means *as such.* If I knew what you were trying to say, the context would help me to figure out which is appropriate.

You could possibly use *non obst.* (*non obstante*), but that means something more in line with *however, notwithstanding*, or *yet.* It only works with contrast.

You could also try *Q.* (*quasi*) if you mean *as it were*. *Tal.* (*talis*) means *of such,* but that's not quite the same as *as such.*

I did a quick check on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_abbreviations) and *viz*. (*videlicet*) means *that is to say.* The only other thing I found was *sc.* (*scilicet*), which literally means *one may know.* Much like *viz*., *sc*. is used to introduce a clarification.

EDIT: Now that I know that you mean to say *a, b, c, and such*, the proper abbrevation is *etc.* for *et cetera*